# Anguilla - How to add multiple Component Links

Tags: 2011, cme, content-manager

Following [this very nice page](https://code.google.com/p/tridion-practice/wiki/AnguillaSnippets), I am trying to insert multiple component links in one go through JavaScript:

```js
var fieldsBuilder = $display.getView().properties.controls.fieldBuilder;

// The Field Type = Tridion.FieldBuilder.FieldTypeHandlers.ComponentLinkField 
var currentField = fieldsBuilder.getField(currentFieldName);

// Get the multivalued data
var selectList = document.getElementById("selectedList");
var selectListOptions = selectList.getElementsByTagName("option");
var newValues = new Array();
for (var i=0;i<selectListOptions.length;i++){
    newValues.push(selectListOptions[i].value);
}

currentField.setValues(currentField.getValues().concat(newValues));
```

For this field type I get a "This field allows a single value only." error, which makes a lot of sense, because the setValues function for this field type gives this:

```
function (b){
  var a=this,c=false;
  if(b&&a.properties.input)if(b.length>1)
  $assert.raiseError("This field allows a single value only.");
  else if(b.length==1){
  // ETC
```

.. while I am trying to insert an array of tcm IDs.

I probably have to do this in a totally different way, but can't really find any. Can anyone here help me out?

Comment: Could this simply be that your schema field supports multiple values?

Comment: It does allow multiple values. I checked that in Tridion and through the isMultivalued() method on the field.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Ok, I've found out how to do it:

```
var currentField = fieldsBuilder.getField(fields[0].getFieldName());
var selectList = document.getElementById("selectedList");
var selectListOptions = selectList.getElementsByTagName("option");

// start at the first empty index or 0 if the first element has no value
var startNumFields = fields.length;
if (fields[0].getValues() == null)
{
    startNumFields = 0;
}

var selectOptionsLength = selectListOptions.length;

for (var j = startNumFields; j < selectOptionsLength + startNumFields; j++)
{
    // console.log("setting: " + selectListOptions[j-fields.length].value);
    if (j == 0)
    {
        fields[0].setValues([selectListOptions[j].value]);
    }
    else
    {
        var addedField = fieldsBuilder.properties.input.insertField(fields[0]);
        addedField.setValues([selectListOptions[j-fields.length].value]);
    }
}
```